# Remote GDB with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug an application remotely with Eclipse CDT.

I got gdbserver and gdb running so I can debug via command line.

I'd like to integrate this stuff into Eclipse. I create a .gdbinit file in my home directory which is corretly loaded by Eclipse. However when i start the debug process I get

"the remote target does not support run"

From the command line, I can use "continue" instead, which work. However I cannot use this alternative from CDT since it is somehow automated.

How can I get Eclipse to use continue instead of run, or how can I make my gdbserver to accept run instead of continue?

Answer (score 1):

If your gdb is recent enough to support the alias command, then you can include the line....

alias run = continue

in your .gdbinit file.